# Update AD Users from CSV, then list changes ONLY

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

We have an HR system that exports all user data to a csv with various headers. I would like to import this csv, update AD users then list just the changes that were made, ignoring any attributes that remained the same.

The csv is like this:

```
Employee Id: 1000
First Name: Joe
Last Name: Bloggs
Known As: Joseph
Work Email: jbloggs@example.com
Company: Some Company Limited
Location: UK
Department: Some Department
Job Role: Some Job Role
Manager Email: somemanager@example.com
```

I believe I would need to match the csv headers with the AD attribute names, and I would like to use the `Work Email` value from the csv as my referencing attribute (to `userPrincipalName` within AD I would assume).

Ideally, the output would be formatted listing the updated user by `userPrincipalName` along with just the attributes that were updated. The attributes that were not changed should show nothing.

For example, if only the `Job Role` was changed, it would show this:

[image: Output]

I hope this makes sense, any help would be much appreciated.

I tried using this but it just updates all values. I also tried using `Compare-Object` with no luck.

```
#Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Log file details
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss"
$Logfile = "C:\logs\$currentDate.log"
function WriteLog
{
Param ([string]$LogString)
$Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
$LogMessage = "$Stamp $LogString"
Add-content $LogFile -value $LogMessage
}

#Store the data from the csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\csv\users.csv"

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {

  ### Organisation ###
      $Email                      = $User.'Work Email'
      $Title                      = $User.'Job Role'
      $EmployeeID                 = $User.'Employee Id'
      $ManagerEmail               = $User.'Manager Email'
      $Manager                    = if ($ManagerEmail) {
         Get-ADUSer -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$ManagerEmail'" -Properties UserPrincipalName | 
         Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
      }

  # Check to see if the user already exists in AD
  # Write-Output "Checking user account for '$Email'"
 Try{
    If ($u = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $Email} -SearchBase "OU=UsersAirspan,DC=airspan,DC=com" -ErrorAction Stop) {
            #User does exist then proceed to update the user account
            Try{
                $u | Set-ADUser -title $Title -employeeID $EmployeeID -manager $Manager -ErrorAction Stop
                WriteLog "Updated title '$Title' and Employee ID '$EmployeeID' and Manager '$ManagerEmail' for '$Email'"
            }
            Catch{
                WriteLog "Error Updating account details for '$Email'"
                WriteLog $_.Exception.Message
                Continue
            }
        }
    }
    Catch{
        #If user does NOT exist, give a warning
        WriteLog "WARNING: A user account with username '$Email' does not exist in Active Directory."
        WriteLog $_.Exception.Message
        Continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the changes by using `Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adreplicationattributemetadata?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Here a short example:

```
$dt = (Get-Date).AddHours(-8)
$server = Get-ADDomainController
$changes = Get-ADReplicationAttributeMetadata -Server $server -Object $u | Where { $_.LastOriginatingChangeTime -gt $dt } | Select AttributeName, AttributeValue
```